# Вызов функции из dll написанной на delphi из python

Tags: python, delphi, dll, ctypes

Импортировал ctypes, подключился к dll. Есть например такая функция:

```
function GetStatusCardReader(var StatusCardReader: Word): Integer; stdcall;
```

Пробую делать так:

```
from ctypes import *

libc = windll.LoadLibrary('C:\test.dll')

func = libc.GetStatusCardReader
func.restype = c_short
print(func)
```

Получаю на выходе <_FuncPtr object at 0x057ABA08>

Как получить значение?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы получить значение, функцию надо вызвать.

```
import ctypes

_dll = ctypes.windll.test # загрузка test.dll из текущего каталога
GetStatusCardReader = _dll.GetStatusCardReader

GetStatusCardReader.argtype = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_uint16)
GetStatusCardReader.restype = ctypes.c_int32

StatusCardReader = ctypes.c_uint16(5) # инициализация параметра некоторым значением
Result = GetStatusCardReader(ctypes.byref(StatusCardReader)) # вызов функции

print(StatusCardReader.value)
print(Result)
```

Поскольку `StatusCardReader` в прототипе функции объявлена как `var`, передавать её надо по ссылке, используя `ctypes.byref`.

Comment: можно явно упомянуть, что windll функции используют stdcall вызовы.

Comment: Спасибо, сработало. А если тип возвращаемого значения пользовательский? Например: function GetStateTerminal(var vStateTerminal: TStateTerminal): Integer; stdcall;  Структура TStateTerminal: 
  VersionDLL: array[0..25] of char
  isActivePinPad: Byte
  ComPortPinPad: array[0..9] of char
  SystemsData: array[1..3] of TListSystemsData. Как быть в таком случае?

Comment: @Максим Почитайте [документацию](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#structures-and-unions) к `ctypes`. Если не поможет - задайте отдельный вопрос.